# iOS 5 return to initial nib view resembling a sign out button

Tags: ios5

this if my first post so please be gentle.

I have an `iOS 5` app (using storyboards) where I want the user to have the ability to sign out, and with that reset all settings in the app, and also return the user to the very first nib view.

I have already used this code:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and the problem with this is that it only sends the user back 1 view and not several.
The issue with this is that I have multiple table views that derive from each other and I want the Sign Out button to remain visible in every single one of these detailed views.
Also, this has to work on both `iPhone` and `iPad` (Universal)

Any suggestions?
Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not assign a BOOL value YES on button click, then in the `viewWillAppear` of each viewController:

(assuming BOOL signingOut)

```
if(signingOut){  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; }
```

Otherwise, just use:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the viewControllers array on the navigation controller.

Or send your logout command to the root controller of the navigation controller and have it pop the navigation controller without animation until there are two left. Then pop the second to last one animated. Then you should still get the navigation animation